Who gives orders to Priya and how?
In Tenet (2020), Priya Singh appears to be a very well-informed, pivotal member of Tenet — an obscure protagonistic organization founded in the future to prevent the future antagonists from getting hold of the algorithm (which can invert the entropy of the whole world and thus annihilate it).
I am having hard time getting my head around how and whom does Priya get orders from.
At 1:46:40, when TP, Neil and Kat are in a stolen ambulance vehicle at a carpark in Oslo, having just been inverted back to normal after going back in time to save Kat from the Sator's gun shot, TP says to Neil:
— Get Priya here to Oslo

— and Neil does it: the next scene is Priya in Oslo talking to re-inverted TP — 2 days before the original TP talks to her in India about what he has found in the Freeport in Oslo and what to do next.
Why would Priya just take that order from Neil and fly to Oslo at short notice? Has she been somehow instructed by Tenet to take orders from Neil? If so, why all the fuss with bungy-jumping their house in India and killing their guards at the beginning of the film if Neil could just order her to see TP? How did TP know in the ambulance vehicle in Oslo that Priya would take orders from Neil?
Further to that, why would Priya believe that "tying up the loose ends" was her job at the end of the movie and attempt to kill Kat? As TP reveals at that point, she was actually working for him, so why couldn't he (the future TP) just order her to leave Kat alone?
